# Calling cordova plugin from angular 2 app in WWW folder

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I would like to check with you guys that i have a problem on calling cordova plugin from www folder. So this is how the project is like:

1) project is built and compile into dist file, the language used is angular2 typescript in visual studio code.
2) the dist file put into cordova project under www file.
3) the above cordova project has added a plugin to display a custom dialog box.

So my question is how to make my angular2 project to call the cordova plugin with passing value from angular2 project.??

Please advices.. i have no code to present as i looking from simple sample that allow my angular 2 dist file to pass values and call the cordova plugin..

Simple sample will do..

Once again for unable to share any code, as i am still figuring out how to work my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to put "cordova.js" into your index.html

Second, the plugin will be available globally. If you are going to use cordova-plugin-device, you can do below.

```
declare var device;
console.log(device);
```

It is all about understanding Angular CLI and Cordova.

Please refer [ABC framework](http://abcframework.com) that automates all the necessary process for you.